# Maven Core compile(9.0.4) with Apache Beam Core(2.2.0) throws exception - Invalid value for MonthOfYear

Tags: java, linux, maven, ubuntu

I am having a problem with the maven compiling in the ubuntu 16. The same code it is compiling into others machines, so looks like the problem it is related to some environmental change, probably automatic update.

If I spend one more day stuck on this, I probably will try format the machine and start from scratch. But, maybe, this question could help other people to find the solution and don't have to do that too.

```
$ mvn compile

[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ my-project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/me/projects/my-project/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5:compile (default-compile) @ my-project ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 28 source files to /home/me/projects/my-project/target/classes
An exception has occurred in the compiler (9.0.4). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 0
    at java.base/java.time.temporal.ValueRange.checkValidValue(ValueRange.java:311)
    at java.base/java.time.temporal.ChronoField.checkValidValue(ChronoField.java:714)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.of(LocalDate.java:269)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.java:336)
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipUtils.dosToJavaTime(ZipUtils.java:109)
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem$Entry.cen(ZipFileSystem.java:1950)
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem$Entry.readCEN(ZipFileSystem.java:1937)
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.getEntry(ZipFileSystem.java:1324)
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.newInputStream(ZipFileSystem.java:550)
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.JarFileSystem.isMultiReleaseJar(JarFileSystem.java:91)
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.JarFileSystem.<init>(JarFileSystem.java:67)
    at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:134)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager$ArchiveContainer.<init>(JavacFileManager.java:517)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.getContainer(JavacFileManager.java:319)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.list(JavacFileManager.java:715)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.list(ClassFinder.java:722)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.scanUserPaths(ClassFinder.java:655)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.fillIn(ClassFinder.java:526)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.ClassFinder.complete(ClassFinder.java:293)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:633)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$PackageSymbol.members(Symbol.java:1120)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symtab.listPackageModules(Symtab.java:810)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.visitTopLevel(Enter.java:344)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCCompilationUnit.accept(JCTree.java:529)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.classEnter(Enter.java:285)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.classEnter(Enter.java:300)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:570)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:554)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:1052)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:923)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:142)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:96)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:90)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:884)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
```

Extra informations:

```
$ mvn version

Apache Maven 3.3.9
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 9.0.4, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle
Default locale: en_NZ, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.13.0-32-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

$ java -version

java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)

$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

pom.xml:

```
        ...
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
            <!-- 
               already try to fix using
               <version>3.7.0</version>
            -->
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            ...
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        ...
```

Commands that I already have tested trying to fix that, with no success:

```
$ sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade 
$ mvn -U clean package
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java # changing to oracle java 8
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java # changing to open jdk 8
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java # changing to oracle java 9
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java # changing to open jdk 9
$ mvn dependency:resolve -U
```

Links that could be useful, but could not fix the problem:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8196777

### Updating...

The problem happens only when:

- one internal project is into the maven dependency;
- the project has at least one unitary test, even if the unitary test does nothing.
- The project has at least one class, even if that class does nothing.

Now, I am trying to load this dependent project as source code to try to discover what is the call, class or method that trigger the problem.

In time, we try to test the same code with the problem "isolated" into another machine, and everything worked. So, for now, the problem looks like be the result of a combination of some java call executed in a special environment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>my.projects</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.234.567</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>my-buggy-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.${minor.version}</version>
    <properties>
        <minor.version>123.456.789</minor.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my.projects.models</groupId>
            <artifactId>models</artifactId>
            <version>111.222.333</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>my-buggy-project</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Did you do what the error message specifically requested you to do?

Comment: Because the source code of the project is company property, I am not sure about what kind of external evaluation I am allowed to apply on it. I am trying to isolate the problem into a non-sensitive data and then run the diagnostic tool.

Comment: First this: `<version>0.${minor.version}</version>` will produce WARNING's during the build...to solve this: http://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html. Apart from that  have tested with newer version of maven-compiler-plugin? If yes have an error message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the package beam-sdks-java-core in the version 2.2.0. This package was being loaded into the package my.projects.models.

Here is the isolated program that replicates the same error message:

### ./pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mock.bug</groupId>
    <artifactId>mock-bug</artifactId>
    <version>0.123</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

### ./src/main/java/com/mock/bug/Main.java

```
 package com.mock.bug;

public class Main {
    public void main(String[] input){
        System.out.println("hello workd");
    }
}
```

### ./src/test/java/com/mock/bug/DummyHealthCheckTest.java

```
package com.mock.bug;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class DummyHealthCheckTest {
    @Test
    public void DummyCheckTest() {
        boolean t = true;
        assertTrue(t);
    }
}
```

### Command to fire the error message:

```
mvn -U clean package
```

If we change the beam-sdks-java-core version from 2.2.0 to 2.1.0, the project can be successfully compiled and tested.

While this information is not enough to fix the issues or to inform why this is only happening on some machines, I believe that is the best answer that can be extracted from this.

I have created one issue request about it with the Apache Beam team https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3693